# Avoiding the -2 in slugs

Tags: urls, slug

so I have a little problem.

I made a WordPress bilingual site with Polylang. Everything works fine, but there is a problem with the slugs. Many pages, although they're not in the same language, have the same names and slugs (i.e. because they're people's names). Still, although Polylang prepends the proper slug with a language code (e.g.  `en/`), the `-2`s still remain, for example there is `/en/john-doe/` and `/fr/john-doe-2/`. I tried adding the post ID to the slug in the permalink settings, but that doesn't solve the problem. It just turns to `/en/55-john-doe/` and `/fr/56-john-doe-2/`.

Is there any natural way to stop this? The added post ID makes the slug unique and I don't understand why it still adds the `-2`.

Comment: Have you asked Polylang support? Off topic: That's why I prefer solutions like [MultilingualPress](https://multilingualpress.org/) (no affiliation with them)

Comment: Because it's not a Polylang problem. When I uninstall Polylang the problem is the same. There is a post ID prepended to the slug, and still the `-2` is added, although `55-john-doe` and `56-john-doe` are different slugs, the latter will always end up as `56-john-doe-2`.